# org.apache.hadoop.hbase.TableNotFoundException: SYSTEM.CATALOG exception with phoenix 4.5.2

Tags: hadoop, hbase, apache-phoenix

I've been trying to integrate `Phoenix 4.5.2` to my existing hadoop cluster.

```
Hadoop Version : 2.7.1
HBase Version : 1.1.2
```

When I try to create table from my phoenix client I'm getting following exception. But I'm able to create table successfully from HBase console.

```
org.apache.phoenix.exception.PhoenixIOException: SYSTEM.CATALOG
    at org.apache.phoenix.util.ServerUtil.parseServerException(ServerUtil.java:108)
    at org.apache.phoenix.query.ConnectionQueryServicesImpl.metaDataCoprocessorExec(ConnectionQueryServicesImpl.java:1051)
    at org.apache.phoenix.query.ConnectionQueryServicesImpl.metaDataCoprocessorExec(ConnectionQueryServicesImpl.java:1014)
    at org.apache.phoenix.query.ConnectionQueryServicesImpl.createTable(ConnectionQueryServicesImpl.java:1259)
    at org.apache.phoenix.query.DelegateConnectionQueryServices.createTable(DelegateConnectionQueryServices.java:113)
    at org.apache.phoenix.schema.MetaDataClient.createTableInternal(MetaDataClient.java:1937)
    at org.apache.phoenix.schema.MetaDataClient.createTable(MetaDataClient.java:751)
    at org.apache.phoenix.compile.CreateTableCompiler$2.execute(CreateTableCompiler.java:186)
    at org.apache.phoenix.jdbc.PhoenixStatement$2.call(PhoenixStatement.java:320)
    at org.apache.phoenix.jdbc.PhoenixStatement$2.call(PhoenixStatement.java:312)
    at org.apache.phoenix.call.CallRunner.run(CallRunner.java:53)
    at org.apache.phoenix.jdbc.PhoenixStatement.executeMutation(PhoenixStatement.java:310)
    at org.apache.phoenix.jdbc.PhoenixStatement.executeUpdate(PhoenixStatement.java:1422)
    at org.apache.phoenix.query.ConnectionQueryServicesImpl$12.call(ConnectionQueryServicesImpl.java:1927)
    at org.apache.phoenix.query.ConnectionQueryServicesImpl$12.call(ConnectionQueryServicesImpl.java:1896)
    at org.apache.phoenix.util.PhoenixContextExecutor.call(PhoenixContextExecutor.java:77)
    at org.apache.phoenix.query.ConnectionQueryServicesImpl.init(ConnectionQueryServicesImpl.java:1896)
    at org.apache.phoenix.jdbc.PhoenixDriver.getConnectionQueryServices(PhoenixDriver.java:180)
    at org.apache.phoenix.jdbc.PhoenixEmbeddedDriver.connect(PhoenixEmbeddedDriver.java:132)
    at org.apache.phoenix.jdbc.PhoenixDriver.connect(PhoenixDriver.java:151)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.JDBCTask.getConnection(JDBCTask.java:370)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.SQLExec.getConnection(SQLExec.java:940)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.SQLExec.execute(SQLExec.java:612)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.UnknownElement.execute(UnknownElement.java:292)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor4.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.dispatch.DispatchUtils.execute(DispatchUtils.java:106)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Task.perform(Task.java:348)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.execute(Target.java:435)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.performTasks(Target.java:456)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeSortedTargets(Project.java:1393)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.helper.SingleCheckExecutor.executeTargets(SingleCheckExecutor.java:38)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeTargets(Project.java:1248)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.Ant.execute(Ant.java:440)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.UnknownElement.execute(UnknownElement.java:292)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor4.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.dispatch.DispatchUtils.execute(DispatchUtils.java:106)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Task.perform(Task.java:348)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.execute(Target.java:435)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.performTasks(Target.java:456)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeSortedTargets(Project.java:1393)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeTarget(Project.java:1364)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.helper.DefaultExecutor.executeTargets(DefaultExecutor.java:41)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeTargets(Project.java:1248)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Main.runBuild(Main.java:851)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Main.startAnt(Main.java:235)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.launch.Launcher.run(Launcher.java:280)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.launch.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:109)
Caused by: org.apache.hadoop.hbase.TableNotFoundException: SYSTEM.CATALOG
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.ConnectionManager$HConnectionImplementation.locateRegionInMeta(ConnectionManager.java:1257)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.ConnectionManager$HConnectionImplementation.locateRegion(ConnectionManager.java:1155)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.ConnectionManager$HConnectionImplementation.locateRegion(ConnectionManager.java:1139)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.ConnectionManager$HConnectionImplementation.locateRegion(ConnectionManager.java:1096)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.ConnectionManager$HConnectionImplementation.getRegionLocation(ConnectionManager.java:931)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.HRegionLocator.getRegionLocation(HRegionLocator.java:83)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.HTable.getRegionLocation(HTable.java:496)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.HTable.getKeysAndRegionsInRange(HTable.java:736)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.HTable.getKeysAndRegionsInRange(HTable.java:706)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.HTable.getStartKeysInRange(HTable.java:1760)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.HTable.coprocessorService(HTable.java:1715)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.HTable.coprocessorService(HTable.java:1695)
    at org.apache.phoenix.query.ConnectionQueryServicesImpl.metaDataCoprocessorExec(ConnectionQueryServicesImpl.java:1034)
    ... 49 more
```

Please suggest what's going wrong here and Phoenix 4.5.2 is compatible with HBase 1.1.2 or not.

Comment: It looks like Phoenix cannot create own additional(meta) tables. Could you attach HBase logs created during connection to HBase via Phoenix (sqlline.py localhost command). Apache Phoenix creates these table during first connection.

Answer (score 4):

Clearing zookeeper will solve the problem.

```
bin/hbase clean --cleanZk
```

Note:- you need to shutdown your master and regionserver before using above command.

Comment: `ZNode(s) [sandbox-hdp.hortonworks.com,16020,1549335973089] of regionservers are not expired. Exiting without cleaning hbase data. ` I shut down the master and regionserver.

Answer (score 1):

Here's what you need to do:

1. Login into hbase zookeeper cli: hbase zkcli
2. check to see if the SYSTEM.CATALOG, SYSTEM.SEQUENCE, SYSTEM.STATS, and SYSTEM.FUNCTION exists by issuing: ls /hbase/table
3. If so... then this is the solution:)
4. Remove all the aforementioned directories: i.e. from the same cli issue rmr /hbase/table/SYSTEM.CATALOG. Do this for all four of the aforementioned files
5. Retry saline... and smile

Answer (score 1):

I have an embedded HBase, I had this error after deleting manually HBase data, so I have had to clean Zookeeper and the rest of HBase with:

```
bin/hbase clean --cleanAll
```

That solved the problem for me.

Answer (score 0):

According to your given logs,

Pheonix was trying to create a table called SYSTEM.CATALOG  in Hbase. But, due to some problem in Hbase, it wasn't able to create it.

The table "SYSTEM.CATALOG" is created the 1st time the connection is made from Pheonix to Hbase.

Therefore, I would recommend checking your Pheonix Configuration for connectivity issues like wrong mapping of IP-Address , forgetting to create a Password less SSH etc.

Answer (score 0):

The above suggestions of cleaning hbase data with only zookeeper running did not help me. What fiannl helped me overcome this error and allow creation of the SYSTEM.CATALOG table and the other associated tables was by copying the hbase-site.xml from the hbase installation into the bin folder of the apache-phoenix installation. 

In my case the hbase conf was in /usr/local/hbase/conf which I copied into /usr/local/apache-phoenix/bin. I just renamed the original hbase-site.xml that was already present in the bin folder to something else, just as a back up. 
This solved the problem of connectivity from sqlline.py as well as SQuirreL client.

This was apart from ensuring the phoenix client libraries were in /squirrel/lib folder for squirrel to work.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, you need to add root user to Apache Ranger's hbase service.

Answer (score -1):

Check your hdfs://.../hbase/data/default/ is exist SYSTEM.CATALOG ? enter image description here

[image]

if there is nothing, you must try to use bin/hbase clean --cleanZk before you use the command, you must stop hbase Master and regionServers,but still keep ZK alive.